# Python Code to Toggle ktinter Image instead of button push

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a GUI interface which has an environmental folder in which I have placed an image of a LED.  I want to change the color of the LED image based on changes in the barometric pressure measured from a BMP180 sensor.  Python3 would be used to determine the changes in pressure.  Instead of a button push to toggle the image, I would like python code toggle the image.

Is this even possible with tkinter and if so could you point me to where I could go to learn how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking for links to a basic tkinter tutorial? That sort of request is off topic for stackoverflow. Have you tried simply using a search engine to find suitable tutorials?

Comment: If the image is a PNG image, better to change the _color_ of the LED to _transparent_.  Then put the image in a `Label` and change the background color of the `Label` based on the pressure measured.

Comment: Thank you acw1668.  I will pursue that if I cannot find a way to change the color of the image.  Sorry for the late response.  Was tied up with some nRF24 receiver programming.